# LightDM is ignoring /etc/login.conf and ~/.login_conf

Tags: shell, freebsd, desktop-environment, lightdm

LightDM is ignoring /etc/login.conf and ~/.login_conf

LightDM is ignoring anything defined `/etc/login.conf`. Even if I modify it and rebuild the database as instructed, LightDM still does not apply anything in that file.

Example:

The default `/etc/login.conf` as installed by FreeBSD contains (snippet)

```
default:\
    :passwd_format=sha512:\
    :copyright=/etc/COPYRIGHT:\
    :welcome=/etc/motd:\
    :setenv=BLOCKSIZE=K:\
    :mail=/var/mail/$:\
    :path=/sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin ~/bin:\
    :nologin=/var/run/nologin:\
    :cputime=unlimited:\
    :datasize=unlimited:\
    :stacksize=unlimited:\
    :memorylocked=64K:\
    :memoryuse=unlimited:\
    :filesize=unlimited:\
    :coredumpsize=unlimited:\
    :openfiles=unlimited:\
    :maxproc=unlimited:\
    :sbsize=unlimited:\
    :vmemoryuse=unlimited:\
    :swapuse=unlimited:\
    :pseudoterminals=unlimited:\
    :kqueues=unlimited:\
    :umtxp=unlimited:\
    :priority=0:\
    :ignoretime@:\
    :umask=022:\
    :charset=UTF-8:\
    :lang=en_US.UTF-8:
```

When using a different display manager (or just console login), the items defined above are setup properly in my session (ie. `setenv`, `charset`, `lang`):

```
% env
BLOCKSIZE=K
HOME=/home/myuser
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=myuser
MAIL=/var/mail/myuser
MM_CHARSET=UTF-8
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/myuser/bin
PWD=/usr/home/myuser
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/fish
SHLVL=1
TERM=xterm
USER=myuser
```

When using LightDM it seems like the file is ignored.

```
% env
COLORTERM=truecolor
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/tmp/dbus-cgHDHagyYe,guid=7c38f126d315fb45ee930de85fc987c1
DESKTOP_SESSION=mate
DISPLAY=:0
EDITOR=vi
ENV=/home/myuser/.shrc
GDMSESSION=mate
GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
HOME=/home/myuser
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=myuser
MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
PAGER=less
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/bin
PWD=/usr/home/myuser
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
SESSION_MANAGER=local/desktop.localdomain.local:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2056
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/fish
SHLVL=1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=myuser
VTE_VERSION=6201
WINDOWID=12583091
XAUTHORITY=/home/myuser/.Xauthority
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=MATE
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/myuser
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/run/user/1001
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=desktop.localdomain.local-1237043009.526093-635089659
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=mate
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_VTNR=8
```

The same behavior occurs when using a per-user `~/.login_conf`.

I know that `login.conf`/`.login_conf` is unique to BSD, but most other display managers (of the ones I've tried: Slim, SDDM) handle it just fine.  Is this a configuration error with LightDM? Or is this a bug with LightDM?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be either an error or a bug. The LightDM `man` page states the configuration file as `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. Further, according to the LightDM project [README.md file](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm), LightDM configuration is provided by the following files:

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Comment: It looks like those config files are to configure LightDM itself and not the environment. See: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?login.conf(5)